# ¿Como modificar flex-direction dependiendo del botón presionado?

Tags: javascript

Código HTML, CSS y JS

Cuando le doy click a unos de los botones, que se muestre como flex-direction: row o column dependiendo donde le diste.

HTML donde pongo el contenedor flex y los elementos flex..

JS: Creamos las funciones para cuando le demos click hagan su funcion de poner en flex-direction: row o column;

CSS le damos al contenedor display flex y alos items flex-direction.

```
    <div id="container">
        <div id="item">1</div>
        <div id="item">2</div>
        <div id="item">3</div>
    </div>
  <button id="rowButton" onclick="rowButton()">Row</button>
  <button id="columnButton" onclick="columnButton()">Column</button>
```

```
// variable
var items = document.getElementById('item');

// Creación de funciónes
function rowButton() {
    if (items.style.flexDirection === "column") {
        items.style.flexDirection === "row";
    }
}

// Creación de otra función
function columnButton() {
    if (items.style.flexDirection === "row") {
        items.style.flexDirection === "column";
    }
}
```

```
//CSS estios
#container {
    display: flex;
}

#items {
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: Hola Ale, la proxima vez utiliza la opción [edit] para agregar la info en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo mas dinámico, ademas de corregir la lógica que tienes, no estaba del todo mal, pero no era necesario obtener cada uno de los `items`, el importante es el contenedor padre, ya que a el le damos la `orientación` en este caso es **container**. Otra cosa que detecte y que no es muy viable es llamar la función desde el **elemento** HTML con `onClick`, revisa mi ejemplo:

```js
//DETECTAMOS LA CARGA DEL DOM
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  //OBTENEMOS EL CONTENEDOR, YA QUE A EL ES AL QUE LE CAMBIAREMOS LA ORIENTACION
  var contenedor = document.getElementById('container');
  //OBTENEMOS LOS BOTONES DINAMICAMENTE
  var boton = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

  //RECORREMOS TODOS LOS BOTONES QUE TENGAN LA CLASE .BUTTON
  boton.forEach(function(e) {
    //DETECTAMOS EL EVENTO CLICK Y SU ELEMENTO DETONADOR
    e.addEventListener('click', function() {
      //VERIFICAMOS EL NOMBRE EN BASE AL ID PARA DAR LA ORIENTACION
      if (e.id === "rowButton") {
        //LLAMAMOS LA FUNCION QUE CORRESPONDA
        rowButton()
      } else if (e.id === "columnButton") {
        //LLAMAMOS LA FUNCION QUE CORRESPONDA
        columnButton()
      }
      //console.log(e.id)
    })
  })

  //FUNCIONES INDEPENDIENTES DEL CAMBIO DE ORIENTACION
  function rowButton() {
    //PARA DAR ALGUN ESTILO SOLO ES CON UN '='
    contenedor.style.flexDirection = "row"
  }
  //FUNCIONES INDEPENDIENTES DEL CAMBIO DE ORIENTACION
  function columnButton() {
    contenedor.style.flexDirection = "column";
  }

})
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
<button id="rowButton" class='button'>Row</button>
<button id="columnButton" class='button'>Column</button>
```

Dime si te sirvio.

Comment: Grasias bro, si me sirvio.. bueno no era directamente con la clase.